# No funcionan los insert SQL en mi hosting web pero sí en mi maquina

Tags: php, mysql

estoy teniendo un problema y me gustaría saber si a alguien le paso o si conoce la solución.

Desarrolle mi sitio web en el servidor local (XAMPP) y todo funciona perfecto. Ningún problema. 100% ok.

El problema fue a la hora de subirla al servidor hosting(este es un servicio gratuito que parkea mi dominio .com), las consultas sql de MODIFICACION e INSERCIÓN no funcionaban, pero sí las SELECT.
Es decir, digamos que tengo dos módulos, uno para enviar consultas y otro para ver las consultas recibidas.
Si creo una consulta mediante el panel de phpmyadmin, esta se puede ver en el modulo de vistas. Pero si quiero enviar una nueva mediante el modulo de envió de consultas, Ésta no llega al servidor, por lo tanto no se logra la inserción.

Todo funciona en mi servidor local, pero en el servidor web hosting sucede lo comentado arriba.

Espero puedan ayudarme y muchísimas gracias de antemano.

Muchas gracias por responder y ayudar...
Con respecto a la primer respuesta, consulte por `SHOW GRANTS FOR`
y me devolvió lo siguiente:

```
    GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'epiz_22808015'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD <secret>
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER, LOCK TABLES ON `mitabla`.* TO 'miuser'@'%'
```

Con respecto a la segunda respuesta, fui corriendo a fijarme si podía crear un usuario, pero al final no se puede. Solo provee un usuario por hosting...

Conocen alguna otra solución? Muchas gracias.

Respondo:
Compre un hosting, y el problema sigue sucediendo. En mi archivo de conexión tengo "localhost" como servidor(el soporte del hosting me dijo que lo ponga, cosa que funciona, porque los select from los ejecuta)
Los insert y updates siguen sin funcionarme en hosting(en mi servidor local funcionan bien).

Me acabo de recordar que una vez abrí la consola y me apareció una advertencia de CORB(no sé bien qué es, ni tampoco sé si tiene que ver con esto)

Alguna otra idea??? Muchas gracias

Comment: Parece que el usuario (con el que estás conectado a la base de datos) no tiene permisos para modificar/crear registros en la base de datos. Puedes verificarlo mediante una consulta como esta: `SHOW GRANTS
    FOR aqui-nombre-de-usuario`

Comment: si lanzas una query para insertar datos desde la consola te funciona? en tu archivo de conexión que tienes especificado como host? localhost, la ip de tu hosting o algún dominio?

Comment: Qué sale en el log de apache cuando intentas hacer la inserción?

Comment: solucionaste? Tengo el mismo problema a diferencia q tengo hosting pago. El error me dá al insertar mas no al seleccionar.

Comment: Hola gracias por responder: Te muestro un poco el codigo:
PHP:[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJGyH.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJGyH.jpg) Aqui parte del codigo que como decia funciona en local mas no en el hosting.
Agradesco alguna ayuda. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Fijate la definición de la tabla formulario, el primer campo lo mandas con '', eso el mysql lo interpreta como null y si ese campo lo tenes como not null te va a tirar error. En wamp por ahi no te tira el error porque tiene otra configuracion o se creo diferente la tabla.
 Otra cosa, temporalmente agrega esto así te muestre el error por lo menos por pantalla:

```
if( !$ejecutar ) {
    echo mysqli_error($link);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Por lo que comentás parecería que el problema es con el usuario que estás utilizando para conectarte a la base de datos en el hosting.  ¿Puede ser que no tenga permisos de inserción y actualización?  Probá de crear otro usuario con estos permisos y cambialo en la cadena de conexión.
¡Suerte!

Comment: No todos los Hosting dejan crear usuarios a voluntad

Comment: exactamente, no deja

Comment: ¿Y ese hosting te da algún tipo de acceso para probar el insert?  ¿Algo como PhpMyAdmin?